# How to reset JSON after send correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

I am trying to build a basic single-page web shop (images of the products, `onclick = "addtocart()"` and a button "Buy" `onclick="buyprem()"`.
On buy, the JSON is sent to my Java Application via a Websocket.
After buying, I want to reset the `JSON` representing the order. But whenever I do this, the default `JSON` is sent.

```
json = {
    products: [],
    composite: false,
    premium: false,
}
i = 0;

function addtocart(name) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById(name);
        elem.innerHTML = "";

    }, 2000);
    document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = i;

    json.products[i] = name;
    i = i + 1;
}

function buyprem() {
    json.premium = true;
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4444");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
    websocket.onopen = () => {
            websocket.send(JSON.stringify(json));
        }
        //--------------------------
    json = {
        products: [],
        composite: false,
        premium: false,
    }
    i = 0;
    //--------------------------
    websocket.close;
}
```

When I comment the marked part out, everything works fine and Java gets the correct `JSON`.
But when I reset the `json` variable in this way, Java gets:

```
Message from client: {"products":[],"composite":false,"premium":false}
```

(With marked code commented out:

```
Message from client: {"products":["dog","donatello","twitch"],"composite":false,"premium":true}
```

where dog, donatello and twitch are the names of the products)

Comment: your function `buyprem()` use assync command,  that's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to do:

```
function buyprem()
{
  json.premium = true

  let StrJSON  = JSON.stringify(json)

  json.products.length = 0
  json.composite       = false
  json.premium         = false
  i                    = 0

  var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4444");
  console.log(StrJSON)
  websocket.onopen = () =>
    {
    websocket.send(StrJSON);
    }

  //--------------------------
  websocket.close();
}
```

because

```
json = {
  products: [],
  composite: false,
  premium: false,
  }
i = 0;
```

use **new** memory for `json`
*(in JS, `json`  is a pointer )*